# Deleted all the Nuget packages in my local package cache, now I can't use VS at all

Tags: .net-core, visual-studio-2017

I deleted all the files and folders inside `C:\Users\myself\.nuget\packages` and now all my `.NET Core` projects complain that `System` or `Void` or anything primitive can't be found. Tried the following

- Nuget.exe -restore c:\path\to\myslnfile.sln -PackagesDirectory C:\Users\myself\.nuget\packages
- Building the solution
- Creating a new project (new projects complain the same thing)

What do I do now?

Comment: Try to close VS, run `dotnet restore` CMD command for your solution and then re-open VS.

Comment: @IlyaChumakov Post that as an answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

1. Close Visual Studio.
2. Run `dotnet restore` CMD command for your solution.
3. Re-open Visual Studio.