# .NET Core Solution builds on command line, but not in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core, visual-studio-2017

I'm building [this .NET solution](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/blob/5.x/src/Elasticsearch.sln), and can restore / build this project fine using the `dotnet build` command:

[image]

However, when I open the same solution in Visual Studio 2017, the build will not complete - I get messages saying that a dependency, `Newtonsoft.Json 10.0.1` cannot be found.

[image]

The dependency in question is referenced from one of the `csproj` files associated with this solution:

[image]

I feel like there might be some setting in Visual Studio which is targeting the wrong .NET Core version, but it's just a hunch.

Could anyone lead me in the right direction on what to check / change?

Many thanks

Comment: Does Solution > Restore NuGet Packages help? This may happen when your shell environment is different than the windows environment VS runs in (global package cache location)

Comment: Hey @MartinUllrich, a restore gives me `All packages are already installed and there is nothing to restore.`, and build still fails - thanks though

Comment: try this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43562917/5112433

Comment: Hi @IlyaChumakov, I've followed the steps in that answer, but get the same results

Comment: Looks bad... Could you remove and re-install the package, or update it to `10.0.2` per solution?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: @KasunKoswattha I'm afraid not. I tried for days but couldn't figure it out.

Comment: @christofr Thanks for the reply. I'm going to reinstall VS. I'll let you know if I find something.

Comment: @christofr I found my problem. Accidentally I have edited a "Dotnet Target" file. I fixed that and now VS is building the projects fine. you might want to check that.