# What is going on with my intellisense and error marking at design time?

Tags: razor, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

I'm currently using Visual Studio 2017 15.1.

I'm using asp.net core Web application (.net framework) and a normal class library.

I seem to be having a hard time to get my cshtml page to stop showing red error lines under my code even though the intellisense understands it and my code compiles and runs.  This is a cshtml page in a class library.  I'm using it for a view component being called by asp.net core 1.1.  but that shouldn't affect the fact that my vs at design time is showing an error but also showing intellisense.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does build/clean the solution removes the red lines for some times ?

Comment: Try this common workaround https://stackoverflow.com/a/43562917/5112433 It helps me... usually.

Comment: Doesn't help, I 've getting this error

The type 'RazorPage<>' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor, Version=1.1.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'

but it's referenced via nuget...?

Comment: Building and cleaning have no affect

Comment: This question [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44460341/installed-nuget-package-visual-studio-claims-assembly-not-referenced) solved this problem for me