# Installed NuGet package, Visual Studio claims assembly not referenced

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

you can see that I have referenced it through nuget, but is still complaining.  This is in a .net 4.6.1 framework class library in an embedded view component.
I'm also using a .net framework asp.net core web app.
I'm having a bunch of issues trying to get razor to work, but this one is a new one. MenuViewPage inherits RazorPage and is located in another assembly.
I think I should just install .net core 2, and aspnetcore.all ;)\

Anyone have any ideas why this is happening?

[image: Razor error]

Comment: Clean and rebuild.  Close VS and reopen.  Manually delete all bin and obj folders then try again.

Comment: The screenshot of the NuGet Package Manager is probably of the web application project, not the class library project. Also, check the warnings, probably showing some reference issues.

Comment: The nguet portion of the screenshot is definitely of the class library.
The error below is the error I'm getting in the page. I included the nuget to show that I have actually referenced the assembly they say are missing. hence why I'm so confused, the version is even correct.

Comment: @Will had no affect on the issue :(

Comment: Uninstall reinstall the package?  Check the reference itself under the References node of the solution.  Might be an error there as well.  Check the path on disk.  Is it there?

Comment: _"The error below is the error I'm getting in the page"_ - I said to check the **warnings**, which you have unselected in your error list (showing 0 of 30 warnings). Reference errors (for example framework incompatibility) are shown as warnings.

Answer (score 0):

So after hours of trying to sort this issue out I've come to a solution:

When creating a web class library, whether you are using it for application parts or you are creating your core project with base classes **I advise you covert it from a normal .net class library to a web enabled one**.

To convert it to a web class library you need to change the project to use the following .csproj, then make sure to run dotnet restore.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup Label="Configuration" Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net461</TargetFramework>
    <RuntimeIdentifier>win7-x86</RuntimeIdentifier>
    <PreserveCompilationContext>true</PreserveCompilationContext>
    <ApplicationIcon />
    <OutputTypeEx>library</OutputTypeEx>
    <StartupObject />
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <DocumentationFile></DocumentationFile>
    <NoWarn>1701;1702;1705;1591</NoWarn>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="1.1.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor">
      <Version>1.1.2</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Runtime">
      <Version>1.1.2</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="System.Net.Http" Version="4.3.2" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="1.0.1" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Make sure you are making the output type a library.
I ran into issues with the assembly info file, it seems to be generated during build now, so I commented out the assembly.info stuff by double clicking "Properties"

I hope this helps someone in the future.