# .NET core with FakeItEasy

Tags: .net, .net-core, fakeiteasy

Can [FakeItEasy](http://fakeiteasy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/quickstart/) work with .NET core? I have installed it through NuGet but I can't reference it in the project as `using FakeItEasy` because it doesn't find it. I have checked under NuGet dependencies and I see it as `FakeItEasy (3.3.2)`

Comment: Yes, it is accessible for .NET Core projects and I was able to add and use that package. Try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/43562917/5112433

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, FakeItEasy > `3.0.0` is compatible with .NET Standard 1.6 which means it will run in .NET Core 1.0 and higher.

You may have problems restoring and using packages, try running `dotnet restore` from command line and closing and re-opening visual studio completely. Also check if `dotnet build` gives the same error message as VS.

Comment: You just repeated my comment, did you really want to help this guy?

Comment: I've been following FakeItEasy's transition to core since its 3.0.0 alpha builds for our company's projects so i felt compelled to write an answer. I'm not sure sure what the exact intention of your comment is but my motivation is primarily that i am huge fan of FakeItEasy.