# How to include Moq in VS 2017 xUnit Project (.NET Core)

Tags: asp.net-core, moq, xunit.net

I was trying to create some unit tests in xUnit using .NET Core and using Moq. I created the project then added Moq using NuGet. I see in the dependencies of the xUnit project under NuGet that Moq (4.7.99) is there but I am not able to use it in code.

When I add:

```
using Moq;
```

I get an error saying Moq could not be found. What am I missing?

Comment: A manual `dotnet restore` from cmd? https://stackoverflow.com/a/43562917/5112433

Comment: @Ilya Chumakov - Thank you, this worked. Please post as answer so I can mark it as the answer.

Comment: You're welcome. I'm sure this is duplicate question, just can't find the original one at this moment.